# log4j rolling appender issue for multiple log file creation

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using log4j for my application for printing logs. Till now, I have only one log file(say X.log) and it is getting rolled after a fixed size, say, 4 MB. Now , I am trying to log some particular requests and responses to a different log file, Y. Log.

My requirement is to roll the Y.log file also, after 4 MB. I am using ***rolling file appender*** for both X and Y logs. Y.log will be created in the same location where X.log is available.

But it seems like now both the log files are not getting rolled over after 4 MB. It is keep on appending to the same logs and the size is increasing. Below is my log4j configuration.

```
<appender name="Xlogfile" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="file" value="/logs/X.log" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="200" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="4MB" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="Ylogfile" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="file" value="/logs/Y.log" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="200" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="4MB" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <level value="INFO"  />
    <appender-ref ref=" Xlogfile " />
    <appender-ref ref=" Ylogfile " />
</root>
```

Could anyone please provide me a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a policy to your appender, like this:

```
<Policies>
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="4mb"/>
</Policies>
```

Comment: Ok Thanks!! What does this policy tag do basically?

Comment: It tells the appender how to behave, in this case for triggeringpolicy it means "The policy to use to determine if a rollover should occur.". For further information take a look at https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

Comment: I added the <Policies> tag inside appender. But, seems like it doesn't work for me. Still the log file is not getting rolled over.

Comment: Maybe it works if you change the way you call your appender (just an idea). Like this: 
<Appender type="RollingFile" name="Ylogfile"> Policies and the other stuff </Appender>

Comment: I tried this also. But no gain. not sure what to do now!!

Comment: The question is about log4j-1 but this answer is about log4j-2.

Comment: I've got a hunch, are you using log4j or log4j2? my answer works in log4j2 but I never used the old version so...

Comment: Actually I'm on log4j. It's not log4j-2.

Comment: Is it easy to migrate to log4j-2?

Comment: never used log4j-1. look for yourself: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/